# How To Forward Declare Template instance member function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

CRTP interface with template member function, has problem with calling 
implementation template member function, due to no forward declaration
of template member function.

Class IF is interface , Class Src is Implementation.

```
    template<class T_Src>
    struct IF {


        template<class T>
        static void f1()
        {
            T_Src::template imp_f1<T>();
        }

template<class T>
    inline void f3()
    {       
        /*this line does not compile*/
        static_cast<T_Src*>(this)->imp_f3<T>();
    }
}


struct Src:public IF<Src>
{
    template<class T>
    static void imp_f1()
    {

    }



    template<class T>
    inline void imp_f3()
    {

    }

};
```

Works ok for static function interface implementation as in IF::f1

But for IF::f3 i get MSVC error

> " C2760: syntax error: unexpected token ')', expected 'expression"

In Summary this works with global and static member template functions, but for class member template functions seems forward declaration is required.

Dont mind solution that includes using some extra template magic to get around this problem such as this

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631621/c-templated-function-and-forward-declarations)

However that fix linked no work for me.

Currently trying to avoid my CRTP interface being limited by not being able to use instance template functions in the interface.

Cheers

Comment: the close vote is strange ...

Comment: Difference between the 2 snippet is not only static call, but `template` keyword missing..

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the `template` keyword before `imp_f3<T>()`, just as you did it for `T_Src::template imp_f1<T>()`:

```
static_cast<T_Src*>(this)->template imp_f3<T>();
```

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840253/template-member-function-of-template-class-called-from-template-function) for an explanation.